# GET filesFolder API issue

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We have a new problem when run this request: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get-filesfolder?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

That is, **GET /teams/{id}/channels/{id}/filesFolder**

Previously, if a Team Channel was created via the API, it wasn't linked to a folder with files, until a user clicks Files in a Teams client and thus initializes it. And until it was initialized, the request would return **Not Found 404**.

However, since around February 25, 2021, in case the authenication uses MFA, we now get this error: **Value cannot be null. Parameter name: token**. But, the Authorization Token **is** present in the request as we verified with a traffic capture. Once you initialize the folder by clicking Files, the request starts to return valid data.

Is this a bug? Thanks.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/.../channels/.../filesFolder?$select=id,name,webUrl,parentReference HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: <...>
Authorization: Bearer ...
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Connection: Keep-Alive

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json
request-id: ...
client-request-id: ...
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West Europe","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"005","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_67"}}
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Date: Mon, 01 Mar 2021 19:38:40 GMT
Content-Length: 310

{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: token",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-03-01T19:38:41",
      "request-id": "...",
      "client-request-id": "..."
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it may fix your current error but concerning the fact that users need to click the Files tab after creating a channel with the Graph. We found a workaround this issue.
If you call the filesFolder endpoint on the General channel (primary channel) before creating your channel with the Graph, the subsequent call to filesFolder on the newly created channel will work without the need of a user to click on the Files tab.

Comment: Thanks for the info! However, in our particular case we're not creating anything, but only read data for purposes of backup, and thus don't want to cause any changes. Cheers!

Comment: @vzubarev - Until unless the user initiate the file tab the graph API will throw and error. This is by design.  Are you facing any issue after initialization.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT We understand that, however the error has changed, and that's the problem for us. Before we would get HTTP 404 and understand what it means. But "failed authentication" is misleading and we cannot handle it correctly.

Comment: Could you please share the request id?

Comment: "request-id": "a8c1f968-87b0-4f6e-875d-cfa489c5e948", but that was about 10 days ago. We have also raised Microsoft Premier case 24487414.

Comment: Could you please check now? Are you still facing issue? If you are still facing the issue could you please share the client- request id and time stamp?

Answer (score 0):

We have Raised a Bug. We don't have ETA to share when it will be available.

Comment: Bug is Resolved now, we have tested this at our end,Hence, we are closing this question for now. If you still face any issue please feel free to reopen the issue